# How do I use microsoft's C++ allocators

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292117.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292134.aspx that Microsoft provides macros and classes for specialized allocators, but I'm not sure what each of the caching strategies are, how to use them.  Can someone explain when to use each of these parts?

- Cache Templates

  - `cache_freelist` - The `cache_freelist` template class maintains a free list of memory blocks of size `Sz`. When the free list is full it uses `operator delete` to deallocate memory blocks. When the free list is empty it uses `operator new` to allocate new memory blocks. The maximum size of the free list is determined by the class `max class` passed in the `Max` parameter.  Each memory block holds `Sz` bytes of usable memory and the data that `operator new` and `operator delete` require.
  - `cache_suballoc` - The `cache_suballoc` template class stores deallocated memory blocks in a free list with unbounded length, using `freelist<sizeof(Type), max_unbounded>`, and suballocates memory blocks from a larger chunk allocated with `operator new` when the free list is empty.  Each chunk holds `Sz * Nelts` bytes of usable memory and the data that `operator new` and `operator delete` require. Allocated chunks are never freed.
  - `cache_chunklist` - This template class uses `operator new` to allocate chunks of raw memory, suballocating blocks to allocate storage for a memory block when needed; it stores deallocated memory blocks in a separate free list for each chunk, and uses `operator delete` to deallocate a chunk when none of its memory blocks is in use. Each memory block holds `Sz` bytes of usable memory and a pointer to the chunk that it belongs to. Each chunk holds `Nelts` memory blocks, three pointers, an int and the data that `operator new` and `operator delete` require.

I've written several allocators myself, but this documentation is just... confusing.

Comment: does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292134.aspx) help?  they mentioned ALLOCATOR_DECL for example and explain why and how to use it.

Comment: I used that page to generate the question.  Rereading it does explain how to use that macro, but not the other types.  Also, the bit that explains how to use the macro has typos that mislead me.  They mix `Alloc` and `alloc<int>`

Comment: Did you start from this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292134.aspx.  It is very clear how to use this allocators and macros. Your links (linked from this page) are just technical details not really necessary to understand for ordinary users. MAybe the header itself will be easier to understand. Did you try to read the header?

Comment: Did not yet read the comments/header, no.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: read that page.  I still don't get the caches or macros, and thus, the allocators at the bottom.

Comment: @MooingDuck the page you linked to was a detailed page on one of the items I think.  That's why I linked you to a more general page which gives an overview.

Comment: @Nerdtron: yeah, I'd read that page as well before posting the question.  I do not understand the cache templates and therefore the macros and allocators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, they really garbled the documentation, didn't they? (I wrote that code when I was at Dinkumware)

The allocators here are policy-based: you can specify a caching policy and a synchronization policy.

The basic idea is to make it easier to write allocators that use internal caches and can be synchronized across threads. There are half a dozen predefined allocators; their names all begin with `allocator_`. Use them if they fit your needs. In the MSDN stuff, look at the first paragraph of the description of the particular allocator; don't read the "Remarks", where they talk about `ALLOCATOR_DECL`;.

You can also use that code to create your own allocators that use the pre-defined caching strategies (templates whose names begin with `cache_`) and synchronization strategies (templates whose names begin with `sync_`), or that use your own caching template and synchronization template. Getting a usable allocator from these pieces is a bit tedious, so the header provides `ALLOCATOR_DECL` as a convenient way to produce all the necessary boilerplate without having to write it yourself. `ALLOCATOR_DECL` takes three arguments: the name of the cache template to use, the name of the synchronization template to use, and the name of the allocator that you're creating. So instead of writing

```
template <class T> class name
    : public Dinkum::allocators::allocator_base<T, sync<cache > >
    {
    public:
        name() {}
        template <class U> name(const name<U>&) {}
        template <class U> name& operator = (const name<U>&)
            {return *this; }
        template <class U> struct rebind
            {    /* convert a name<T> to a name<U> */
            typedef name<U> other;
            };
    };
```

you would write `ALLOCATOR_DECL(cache, sync, name);`. `allocator_base` does the heavy lifting; the allocator itself has to be a derived type, so that it can handle `rebind` correctly. (The `Dinkum` in that code comes from the Dinkumware documentation; I don't know what namespace the Microsoft stuff puts these names in, but presumably the macro puts the right name there).

For the cache templates:

- `cache_freelist` maintains a linked list of node-sized blocks; the maximum size of the list is set by the template parameter `Sz`, and node allocation is managed with `operator new` and `operator delete`.
- `cache_suballoc` adds another layer that manages a block of `Nelts` node blocks, all allocated as a single blob; allocation of a new element looks first to the free list, and if there is nothing free, allocates a new blob. Memory blocks are not deleted until the allocator is destroyed.
- `cache_chunklist` allocates memory in blobs (like `cache_suballoc`), but doesn't use a common free list; when a block is released it goes back into the free list for its blob. When all of a blobs blocks have been released, the blob itself is deleted.

Comment: Apperently my question was poorly worded as to exactly what I was looking for, so I rewrote it.  Specifically, what are each of the caching templates?

Comment: @MooingDuck - thanks for the edit. I wasn't thinking straight. Writing while sitting in the C++ Standards Committee meeting.

Comment: I'm honored you answered my question! :D

Answer (score 0):

The first subquestion is easy. When to use them? When profiling shows an issue with the default allocator. That alone makes the question irrelevant to most developers.

Some of the macros use the verb "yields", which loosely means "eventually expands to, probably through multiple steps".

The cache templates save deallocated blocks for later re-allocation. You'd pick the cache which works best for your allocation pattern, the one which has the best tradeoff between reuse % and cache size (see profiling above).

Some cache templates have a finite number of freed blocks, implemented via `freelist<>`. The Max classes determine how long such a `freelist` can become.

The allocators finally are pre-composed combinations of the above.

Comment: So what's the difference between `cache_freelist`, `cache_suballoc`, and `cache_chunklist`?